# Nested conditional statement in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements, conditional-operator

How can I make a nested conditional statement in PHP?

I'm trying to:

```
if (A=="blah" && B=="bleh" && C=="bloh" && (D=="bluh" || E=="blih"))
```

Easier to read:

```
if (A AND B AND C AND (D OR E))
```

Comment: that looks right, but you are missing the $

Comment: -1 for not checking for PHP errors first.

Comment: Can't see what's wrong with the question. Both the question and accepted answer helped me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You almost got it right, but you were missing the $'s

```
if($A=="blah" && $B=="bleh" && $C=="bloh" && ($D=="bluh" || $E=="blih"))
```

Comment: I was writing in pseudo code, I didn't mean it to be real :) For some reason it works now, thanks!

Comment: You were almost right though! ;-) By the way, you can use `and` and `or` in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If you are also asking for readability, this might be an option too:

```
$conditionA = $A == "blah";
$conditionB = $B == "bleh";
$conditionC = $C == "bloh";
$conditionD1 = $D == "bluh";
$conditionD2 = $E == "blih";
$conditionD = $conditionD1 || $conditionD2;

if (conditionA && conditionB && conditionC && conditionD){
//...
}
```

Shorter or more useful names might be a good idea as well.

Comment: To my thinking, that makes it a lot less readable.

Comment: @DC: Always or when conditions are used only once?

Comment: In this particular instance, I find it's harder to read the entire conditional, as I have to keep going back and forth between the actual `if` statement and the individual part definitions in order to follow the relationships.

Comment: Ok, I share that. Without renaming and probably if not reused, the additional booleans can make life harder. As written, it's just an option depending on the actual context.